# Firebase not behaving as it should in my node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Firebase is acting really funky in my node.js app and I don't know why.

For instance if I have a varible that looks something like this:

```
var AllItems= {"itemList":[{"id":1,"name":....}
```

I can log it and have it spit out everything correctly but if I try get it by the inner array, like this.

```
var itemList = AllItems[itemList]
```

It returns `undefined`.

All if I try spit out each one at a time in a loop like this:

```
for(i in AllItems){
console.log('i: ',i)
}
```

It spits out something like this:

```
i:  0
i:  1
i:  2
i:  3
```

all the way to `i:  7581` and I only have 13 Items assuming it is logging there index number but its not and it should be spitting out just that one `itemList` where the above `[{"id":1,"name":....` would be its value.

My firebase modules are

```
  var Firebase = require("firebase");
   var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
```

Comment: How is Firebase part of the problem?

Comment: I expect that you're running into Firebase's array coercion. Since it's hard to be sure, I'll just refer you to where that is documented: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase

Comment: @PierreC. I was loading firebase data into my `var AllItems`. @FrankvanPuffelen looks like it could have been it but I just reverted back to a working version but Im going to look over that anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is that you do not understand how to access your AllItem object properly.

### Access one itemList

In your question you try to access your itemList this way `AllItems[itemList]`. There, `itemList` is considered a variable, which is `undefined`. And `AllItems[undefined]` is undefined.

Here are the two ways to access it:

```
var itemList = allItems['itemList'];
var itemList = allItems.itemList;
```

### Loop on itemLists

I do not know how you get to `i: 7581` but this is how I did it:

```
for(var key in allItems) {
  console.log(allItems[key]); 
}
```

This logs every itemList in allItems.

#### Snippet

I made a little snippet with everything I just explained.

```js
var allItems = {
  "itemList": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "item1"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "item2"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "item2"
  }]
};

// Log itemList (2 ways)
console.log(allItems['itemList']);
console.log(allItems.itemList);

var itemList = allItems.itemList;

// Log every item in itemList
itemList.forEach(function (item) {
  console.log(item);
});

// Log every itemList in allItems
for(var key in allItems) {
  console.log(allItems[key]); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out of your day to share this, very insightful.  I tried it with your snippets and also did variations of this before but still no luck. I found if I ran `console.log(allItems)` twice it would only log the first and the second would return `undefined`. I still not sure why but I ended up reverting to a working version and just copy pasted the new into the working old version and got it working. But thanks again I really am appreciative.